# How can I group rows in Google Sheets and sort

Tags: google-sheets

I have been trying to group rows in Google Sheets.  I have a heading (name) and then the information that must be included on the sheet without losing the spacing or lines.  How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Welcome to webapps. _..._.Sorry but I fail to understand what you mean. Please share a screenshot or a sample sheet of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array like this :

```
 ={A2;A4:A8;C1:C4}
```

It will return an array like this :

```
A2  
A4  
A5  
A6  
A7  
A8  
C1  
C2   
C3   
C4
```

You are just limited by the number of column, every range must have the same number of columns.

For a single row it's the same deal except you need to replace `;` with `,`:

```
={A1:D1,I1:K1}
```

It returns :

```
A1  |  B1  |  C1  |  D1  |  I1  |  J1  |  K1  |
```